# How to interpret the statistical results from a medical study

Tags: research, statistics, cardiovascular-disease

I would greatly appreciate help in understanding the significance of the snippet below copied from a study at the link below.

"Compared with participants eating three meals per day, the multivariable-adjusted HRs for participants eating one meal per day were 1.30 (95% CI 1.03 to 1.64) for all-cause mortality, and 1.83 (95% CI 1.26 to 2.65) for CVD mortality."

Am I correct in interpreting the results as follows.

HRs means hazard ratios. CI is the confidence interval.   With 95% confidence the study concludes that participants who eat 1 meal /day are  .03% to .64% more likely to die over whatever time period they looked at.

Specifically is the cohort .03% to .64%, .3% to 6.4%, or 30% to 64% more likely to die?  I am not sure if they are using percentages or not, but it seems that is the typical way to do it.

https://www.jandonline.org/article/S2212-2672(22)00874-7/fulltext

Comment: Hazard **ratio**.

Comment: The full text is behind a pay wall and without that, it's hard to know. My *guess* would be 30% to 64% but that's a guess.

Comment: Upon further reflection it looks like the cohort has a 53% greater chance of dying with a confidence interval of 95%.  I base that on 1.83- 1.30. Does that make sense to anyone?